# How to integrate Bootstrap to a react project

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have custom files such as:

- bootstrap.css
- bootstrap.js
- owl-carosel.min.css
- owl-carosel.min.js

I want to add them locally from my assets folder inside src to my `index.js`.

I have tried adding them to my `index.html`, but the problem is I have to move my assets folder to a public folder.

When I try adding them using an `import` statement, it fails to compile.

Error:

> Failed to compile
>
> ./src/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css)
> Module not found: Can't resolve '../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot' in '/home/cedex12/Gokul/food-day/src/assets/css'

Can we add them like this:

- Step1: `bootstrap: 'file:/path/to/your/repo'`
- Step2: `npm install`

Comment: Hi Gokul, welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question was probably downvoted because it can be easily googled. It's good to attempt to solve your own problems first, then use google for more acute issues you're having trouble finding/solving.

Comment: Wait what you actually update all your question !!!!! Never do that like this but open a new one!!!

Answer (score 0):

With js you can use the function [import()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) that allow you to import external js file in a js file ;) Just read the doc

Comment: It fails to compile when i add these file.I can add regular css file but these files.Can we add them through dependencies  Error i get: Failed to compile
                                                                                                                 ./src/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css)
Module not found: Can't resolve '../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot' in '/home/cedex12/Gokul/food-day/src/assets/css'

Comment: it is another problem than asked one. It sounds like you have not url `file-loader` and|or `url-loader' on your webpack loaders collection.

Comment: Can we add them through dependency like Step1 : bootstrap': 'file:/path/to/your/repo' 
   Step2  :  npm install

Answer (score 0):

try using react-bootstrap framework its build with react components! here a link:https://react-bootstrap.github.io/

Comment: I get complete html template build which have bootstrap implemented through class and tomuch trouble to download and implement owl carousel from non I have local file in my hand .So I am looking for a simpler method

Comment: slick slider build for react is good and better then bootstrap carousel if u want to check it out here a link https://react-slick.neostack.com/